# Quick question: Why are the limits of integration in a definite integral not included in the domain?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This question may seem a bit silly but it has been bugging me for a while now as I kept running into it in various occasions.

The first time was when I was studying comparison test for improper integrals and one [example](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx#:%7E:text=Example%202-,Determine%20if%20the%20following%20integral%20is%20convergent%20or%20divergent.,-%E2%88%AB) asked to find out if the following integral converges or diverges using the comparison test.
$$\int_{{\,3}}^{{\,\infty }}{{\frac{1}{{x + {{\bf{e}}^x}}}\,dx}}$$
In the solution, it said that $x \ge 3$ based on the lower limit of integration.

However, in another [example](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx#:%7E:text=Example%206-,Determine%20if%20the%20following%20integral%20is%20convergent%20or%20divergent.,-%E2%88%AB), for the integral
$$\int_{{\,1}}^{{\,\infty }}{{\frac{{{{\bf{e}}^{ - x}}}}{x}\,dx}}$$
it said that $x > 1$ and that $1$ is always smaller than $x$.

This is rather contradictory for me because one asserted that the endpoint is included in the domain of possible values $x$ can take while the other strictly excluded it. Is there something special about the two problems that determines whether the limits of integration will be included?

I had also encountered this "issue" in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFnOaaXwOJk&t=279s) that explained the proof that $\frac{22}{7}$ is greater than $\pi$.
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2} \, dx = \frac{22}{7} - \pi$$
At 4:39 into the video, Presh said to consider $x$ in the open interval $(0,1)$. But, why not $[0,1]$?

I would highly appreciate it if someone can explain each of these cases, but a general answer is also welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference whether you include the endpoints or not, since a single point doesn't affect the value of the integral. So if it serves your purpose to exclude the endpoints, you are free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a simple fact

*if the function $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f(x)\ge0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$ then*
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0
$$
*if and only if $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in[a,b]$.*

Indeed, if $f(c)>0$ for some $c\in [a,b]$, then there is $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\ge f(c)/2$ for every $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap[a,b]$. Thus there exist $p,q\in[a,b]$, with $p<q$ and $f(x)\ge f(c)/2$ for $p\le x\le q$. Thus
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^p f(x)\,dx+\int_p^q f(x)\,dx+\int_q^b f(x)\,dx
$$
The first and the third terms in the right-hand side are $\ge0$, whereas the middle term is $\ge(q-p)f(c)/4>0$.